# After form submission display a popup successfull message using jquery fancybox plugin

Tags: php, jquery, forms, popup, fancybox

After successful form validation, I want to display a popup successful message using fancybox plugin.

Here is my php code -

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['cfsubmit'])){  

//if no erros, echo the results 
if(!$errorExists){
    echo "<div id='c_confirm'><p><span class='check_mark'></span>Thank you for contacting With us. One of our customer service representatives will get back to you within 24 hours.</p></div>";
            $emailTo = "myemail@gmail.com";
    if (!isset($emailTo) || ($emailTo == '') ){
        $emailTo = get_option('admin_email');
    }

    $subject = 'Contact Form from '.$fname;
    $body = "First Name: $fname \n\nLast Name: $lname \n\nCheck In date: $check_in_date \n\nCheck Out date: $check_out_date \n\nApartment type: $apart_type \n\nPhone: $phone \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments: $comments";
    $headers = 'From: '.$fname.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";
           wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);


}else{
    echo "<h3>Error!</h3>".$errors;
}

}?>
```

I want to display this message , in a popup box. Using jquery fancybox plugin.

```
<div id='c_confirm'><p><span class='check_mark'></span>Thank you for contacting With us. One of our customer service representatives will get back to you within 24 hours.</p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have properly loaded jQuery and fancybox js and css files, your could do :

```
if(!$errorExists){
    $fancymessage = "<div id='c_confirm'><p><span class='check_mark'></span>Thank you for contacting With us. One of our customer service representatives will get back to you within 24 hours.</p></div>";
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $.fancybox("<?php echo $fancymessage; ?>");
    });
    </script>
    <?php 
    $emailTo = "myemail@gmail.com";
    if (!isset($emailTo) || ($emailTo == '') ){
        $emailTo = get_option('admin_email');
    }
    ... etc.
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/25fSq/)**

Comment: @hocpana You should consider accepting the answer if it works for you. That way we know your problem is solved.